# How should get the expectation value of $1/r$ in the hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, hydrogen, orbitals

I have a question of quantum mechanics.
I want to calculate \begin{align}\left\langle \frac{1}{r} \right\rangle \end{align} in the state $n, l$ of the hydrogen atom.

In the textbook I have, the wavefunction is given as
\begin{align} \psi_{nlm} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{2Z}{na_0}\right)^3\frac{(n-l-1)!}{2n[(n+l)!]^3}} e^{-Zr/na_{0}}\left(\frac{Zr}{na_{0}}\right)^{l}L^{2l+1}_{n+l}\left(\frac{2Z}{na_{0}}r\right)Y^{m}_{l}(\theta, \phi)\end{align}

Though I referred [this link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282189/), the index of the associated Laguerre polynomial and the normalization coefficient are quite different hence I cannot get an idea how to simplify the result.
How can I calculate the expectation of \begin{align}\left\langle \frac{1}{r}\right\rangle?\end{align}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expectation value for $\frac{1}{r}$ in the $|nlm\rangle$ state of hydrogen](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282189/)

Comment: You linked to a question in which one of the answers *does the integral*! So why are you asking how to do the integral?

Answer (score 1):

As the potential in the hydrogen hamiltonian, is
$$
V(r)= - \frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}
$$
The easiest way is to use the formula for the energy
$$
E_{n,l}= \frac{m_e e^4} {2(4\pi \epsilon_0)^2 \hbar^2 n^2},
$$
in conjuction  with  the Feynman-Hellmann formula
$$
\frac{\partial E_{n,l}}{\partial \lambda} = \langle n,m| \frac{\partial H}{\partial \lambda}| n,l\rangle
$$
and just differentiate $E_{nl}$ with respect to $e$.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. But since I didn't learned the Feynman-Hallmann formula yet, I would like to get the result only by basic calculus.

Comment: Feynman-Hellman is elementary and is taught in intro classes under the name "1st order pertubation theory." It's  much simpler  than integrating Laguerre functions! If you have this problem in an intro class, I think you are *expected* to use F-H.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to be able to take the integrals of a product of two Laguerre polinomials with powers and exponents. This is where one usually has to turn to the classics, such as [Gradshtein & Ryzhik](https://www.amazon.fr/Table-Integrals-Products-I-S-Gradshteyn/dp/0122947606) or [Abramovitz & Stegun](https://www.amazon.fr/Livres-Milton-Abramowitz-Irene-Stegun/s?rh=n%3A301061%2Cp_27%3AMilton%20Abramowitz%20Irene%20Stegun), whereas Mathematica is often powerless.

These books are available in any university library, and the older editions also can be found for download.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I will refer to them.

Comment: Note that these two books are not exactly the same: Gradshtein has more in terms of formulas for integrals, whereas Abramovitz has more on the properties of the special functions. In this case you will probably find the former more helpful.